# How do you get the new product ID after programmatically creating the product?

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1.3, save, repository

I have a configurable product and am trying to programmatically create a new simple product and then associate it with my configurable product.  This is what I have so far...

```
$newProduct = $this->_productFactory->create();
$newProduct->setName('Test Product')
    ->setTypeId(Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
    ->setSku('test-product')
    ->setPrice($configurableProduct->getPrice())
    ->setWeight($configurableProduct->getWeight())
    ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
    ->setAttributeSetId($configurableProduct->getAttributeSetId())
    ->setData('my_product_attribute', 'sample_value');
$this->_productRepository->save($newProduct);
$newId = $newProduct->getId();
```

However, when I try to get the new product ID `$newId` after using the product repository to save, the value is `null`.  The simple product saves correctly, but I need the ID to be able to associate it with the configurable one.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here's the situation: Because of how the product save works, `$this->_productRepository->save($newProduct);` does not reflect changes back onto your `$newProduct`. It's actually [creating a new `Product` instance and copying your data onto it](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/cb3b5d1e0715632c15d8a9697538afca4083a859/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php#L580) inside there. Sound slow and inefficient? Yeah. This approach probably makes data integrity easier to maintain though.

To walk through that core method:

1. You pass a `Product` into the method, used as `$product`.

   ```
   public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false)
   ```
2. They re-load the product by SKU, and copy link data from it onto yours.

   ```
       $existingProduct = $this->get($product->getSku());
       $product->setData(
           $this->resourceModel->getLinkField(),
           $existingProduct->getData($this->resourceModel->getLinkField())
       );
   ```
3. They convert your product into a data array.

   ```
   $productDataArray = $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter
       ->toNestedArray($product, [], \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
   $productDataArray = array_replace($productDataArray, $product->getData());
   ```
4. They create a new `Product` object from that data.

   ```
   $product = $this->initializeProductData($productDataArray, empty($existingProduct));
   ```
5. They save that new `$product`.

   ```
       unset($this->instances[$product->getSku()]);
       unset($this->instancesById[$product->getId()]);
       $this->resourceModel->save($product);
   ```
6. Finally, they load the product *again*, and return that.

   ```
   return $this->get($product->getSku());
   ```

What this means in practice: `$newProduct` (the `Product` you passed in) will not give you any data about the save. It's exactly the same object after saving as you had before, because it's not touched directly (except for in #2). But `$this->_productRepository->save()` actually returns the saved product model. Basically, they're shuffling objects around, and that complicates things.

With all that in mind, try this for your product save:

```
$newProduct = $this->_productFactory->create();
$newProduct->setName('Test Product')
    ->setTypeId(Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
    ->setSku('test-product')
    ->setPrice($configurableProduct->getPrice())
    ->setWeight($configurableProduct->getWeight())
    ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
    ->setAttributeSetId($configurableProduct->getAttributeSetId())
    ->setData('my_product_attribute', 'sample_value');
$newProduct = $this->_productRepository->save($newProduct);
$newId = $newProduct->getId();
```

Note that we're reassigning `$newProduct` to the *result* of the repository save. That gives us the saved ID and anything else that resulted.

Comment: Ah, fantastic... thank you for explaining this so clearly!